# Xtext separate code generator from grammar project

Tags: java, code-generation, xtext, xtend

i'm wrinting a code generator and i was thinking in separate the code generator from de grammar. I've get success in generate the code of " MyDslGenerator.java", but my problem is how to integrate this project with the project of the grammar.
The idea for this is to modularizate my project, having one part responsible for the grammar and ui generation, and another part responsible for the code generation.
Every time i try to setup the code generator that is in another project, i get an error, such as that some methods wasn't implemented. What is the best way to separate my code generator from my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about having two versions and bind them in runtime and ui. alternatively i dont know if is still working http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/moving-an-xtend-generator-into-its-own-plugin/ (at least the idea should be still valid)

Comment: I have read that post while ago, but no success, because the generator is embedded to xtext project. I've tried to generate only the code generator class in another project and call it in same way as you did using an context menu, but i get errors of classes that was not implemented. After some research, many people say that i need to implement IGenerator interface, but how i call the "doGenerate" method from another plugin??

Comment: Your Plugin has to hook in AS builderparticipant

Comment: I tried to create the plugin hooking as builder participant but i get " No implementation for org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot was bound " and "  No implementation for org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGenerator was bound ". What does it all mean?

Comment: I've solved the implementation problem, but now i'm getting this:

org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant$BuilderParticipantReader  - Plug-in org.xtext.example.mydsl.generator was unable to load class org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.MyDslExecutableExtensionFactory.

Comment: Of course the class has to be created or imported via plugin dependency

Comment: After redo the steps i guess it's working, because if i change anything in the external generator plugin that can break the generator, it really does. But i think i miss something, i put a "println( 'external generator')" inside the Generator.xtend, but after execute the save command to generate my code, anything appears in my console.

Comment: At which console are you looking?

Comment: btw it is just explained the idea, since some apis have changes since then you have to port the idea as well

Comment: The console is from the eclipse, not from the application, when i do the same in a default project it works and i get the printed text at my development IDE. How can i make the external generator plugin to generate my code?

Comment: Hi I gave it a try and it worked nicely but it still is a kind a workaround you need to know what you are doing

Comment: Hi Christian, i finally fixed, my problem is that i forgot to add the implementation of IGenerator in my RuntimeModule. Now my project is working beautifully. Thanks for the help ;)